# A three way toggle should display the same div with number of checkboxes one with Disabled , Checked and Unchecked in JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have `Three-way toggle`, where Each on click should **display** the three different States.

```
Disabled -- All CheckBoxes should be left UNCHECKED
Default -- All CheckBoxes should be left CHECKED AND DISABLED
Enabled -- All CheckBoxes should be left CHECKED
```

Using **Only one set of checkbox**, the three different states should occur.

How could I do this in **CSS** and in **JS**?

```
<div class="tw-toggle">
   <input type="radio" name="toggle" class="Toggle1" value="false">
   <label class="toggle toggle-yes"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></label>
   <input checked type="radio" name="toggle" class="Toggle2" value="-1">
   <label class="toggle toggle-yes"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></label>
   <input type="radio" name="toggle" class="Toggle3" value="true">
   <label class="toggle toggle-yes"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label>
   <span></span>
</div>

//Checkbox Input
   <div class="form-group">
      <p> Disabled List of digits</p>
         <div class="form-check">
             <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox" value="0">
              <label class="form-check-label">0</label>
          </div>
         <div class="form-check">
             <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox" value="1">
             <label class="form-check-label">1</label>
          </div>
         <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox"value="2">
              <label class="form-check-label">2</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox"value="3">
              <label class="form-check-label">3</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-check">
             <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox" value="4">
             <label class="form-check-label" for="disable4">4</label>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**Script**:

```
 function toggledDiv() {
    const toggles = [".Toggle1", ".Toggle2", ".Toggle3"];
   for (let i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
      let toggleElem = document.querySelector(toggles[i]);
      const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
         toggleElem.addEventListener("change", () => {
             if (toggleElem.value === 'false') {
                // all checkBoxes should be UNCHECKED
             }
             else if (toggleElem.value === 'true') {
                  // all checkBoxes should be CHECKED
                 checkboxes.setAttribute('checked');
              }
             else {
              // all checkBoxes should be CHECKED AND DISABLED
                checkboxes.setAttribute('disabled');
             }

           });
         }
      }
```

How could I do this different states using ONLY one set of checkboxes using JS AND CSS?

Could anyone please help?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a reasonable start. However, you shouldn't add event listeners inside loops that you use often. You'll end up adding the event listeners over and over again. Other than that, you were well on your way to get it to work. Here's a working example of how I would do it (some explanation can be found within the comments of the code):

```js
// Make  sure DOM is finished loading
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e){
    // Get all radio buttons
  const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="toggle"]');
  
  // Add event listeners to each radio button
  for(let i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++){
    radioBtns[i].addEventListener("click", handleToggleEvent, false);
  }
});

function handleToggleEvent(){
    // Get current radio button state
  const radioBtnState = document.querySelector('input[name="toggle"]:checked').value;
  
  // Get all checkboxes
  const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="myGroup"]');
  
  // Loop through each checkbox and set attributes according to radio button state
  for(let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
    if(radioBtnState === '-1'){
        checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
      checkBoxes[i].setAttribute('disabled', true);
    } else if(radioBtnState === 'true') {
        checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
      checkBoxes[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else if(radioBtnState === 'false') {
        checkBoxes[i].checked = false;
      checkBoxes[i].setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.tw-toggle {
  /* background: #95A5A6; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:relative;
  border: 2px solid #95A5A6;
}

.tw-toggle label {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #95A5A6;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  /* cursor: pointer; */
}

.tw-toggle input {
  /* display: none; */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tw-toggle span {
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
  line-height: 21px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:#fff;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left: 22px;
  top: 2px;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tw-toggle input[value="false"]:checked ~ span{
  background:#e74c3c;
  left:2px;
  color:#fff;
}

.tw-toggle input[value="true"]:checked ~ span{
  background:#27ae60;
  left: 46px;
}
.tw-toggle input[value="-1"]:checked ~ span{
  background:#95A5A6;
  left: 23px;
}

.tw-toggle input[value="false"]:checked + label,.tw-toggle input[value="true"]:checked + label{
  color:#fff;
}
.tw-toggle input[value="-1"]:checked + label{
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="tw-toggle">
  <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="false">
  <label class="toggle toggle-yes"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></label>
  <input checked type="radio" name="toggle" value="-1">
  <label class="toggle toggle-yes"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="true">
  <label class="toggle toggle-yes"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label>
  <span></span>  
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <p> Disabled List of digits</p>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox" value="0" checked disabled>
    <label class="form-check-label">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox" value="1" checked disabled>
    <label class="form-check-label">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox"value="2" checked disabled>
    <label class="form-check-label">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox"value="3" checked disabled>
    <label class="form-check-label">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="myGroup" type="checkbox" value="4" checked disabled>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="disable4">4</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your good explanation! But, I couldn't understand "you shouldn't add event listeners inside loops that you use often. You'll end up adding the event listeners over and over again" and why do you use "false"  here ?  radioBtns[i].addEventListener("click", handleToggleEvent, false); Thank you.

Comment: @shada Your `toggleDiv` function has this part: `toggleElem.addEventListener`. So every time the `toggleDiv` function is called, it adds the event listener to the buttons. Even though it already exists since the first time it was used. As for the third parameter (false) in the event listener declaration, it's not really needed as that's the default if not specified. It has to do with event bubbling and having multiple events within the same parent element. If you set it to true, the event will take priority over other events that don't have it set to true.

Comment: thank you so much! @icecub But, What does true/false mean here and in event listeners in general? If it is false, the event wont take priority?

Comment: No, it's honestly not something you should be worried about yet. Event bubbling is a bit more advanced and honestly, even in my 20+ years of experience, never really been an issue to me at all. Anyway, I'll try to explain it a bit. Lets say you have this code: `<div><button></button></div>`. So here you have a parent div and a child button. Because the button is inside the div. Now lets say you put a click event on the button and a click event on the div. When the user clicks on the button, they also click on the div. Which one takes priority? That's where the true / false comes in

Comment: @shada That's just a very simple explanation and not entirely how it all works, but for now that should be enough for you to get the idea behind it :)

Comment: Thank you so much! When the user clicks the button, the button should be given the prirority  than the div ? Thats why we use 'False' ?  If the div is given priority, then we use true? This is the idea behind ?